# Preset package-wide configuration for requirejs packages

Tags: javascript, configuration, package, requirejs

I am currently working myself into requirejs, to do this I started to write a small package. The package consists of one `main.js`, the entry point for the application and several other modules that will be loaded into `main.js` through a call to `require`.

The package has several options that can be configured during runtime, to ease maintenance I have a central `configuration.js` that is loaded whenever needed. The contents of `configuration.js` is just an object that maps key to value, no functionality or anything. Just a key-value map.

Now requirejs allows to pass options to packages, the configuration is done through the requirejs config. The problem I have is, that it is only available in the `main.js` and not in other modules in the package, also I could not find a way to set default values unless I hardcode them into the `main.js`.

My current approach (the one with the `configuration.js`) is to merge the configuration given to requirejs with the contents of my `configuration.js` in the `main.js`.

`main.js`

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var $ = require('jquery'); // Could be any library that offers an "extend"
                               // feature that allows "deep" copies.

    var config = require('configuration'); // Load configuration file

    $.extend(true, config, module.config()); // Overwrite default values with 
                                             // set values


    var otherfile = require('anyotherfile);
    otherfile();
});
```

`anyotherfile.js`

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var config = require('config'); // Loads configuration, package-wide
                                    // options are set

    // module.config() will be empty. Unless I explicicy specify the
    // configuration for this one module in the "requirejs.config"

    return function() {
        // Something that can be configured
    };
});
```

This way of setting configuration options makes me dependent on an additional library or my own implementation of an `extend` functionality (it's not much code, but still more code than no code) plus there are two points where I have to look for possible configuration mistakes which makes it harder to find errors.

So now I am searching for a better way to pass a package-wide configuration all while trying to avoid more than one point of failure. (This might be hard cause somewhere I have to store the default values if I don't want to hardcode them.) And of course the solution should not depend on any additional libraries or my own `extend` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with jrburke about the problem the best solution is to do the extending of the config array in the `configuration.js`.

Example of the file `configuration.js`

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var $ = require('jquery'); // need jQuery for extend
    var config = {
        key: value,
        ...
    };
    return $.extend(true, config, module.config());
});
```

So there is no more need to do this in the `main.js`.

The only disadvantage of this approach is that in the `requirejs.config` you have to address
`package/configuration` and not `package`.

Example of the `requirejs.config`

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        "package/configuration": {
             key: value
        }
    }
});
```